# Copy list items from one list to another with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, html-lists

I'm trying to get a list of items from one list and put it into another list.

This is what I have:

```
$("#change").click(function () {
    arr = $('#old').map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    $.each(arr, function (index, item) {
        $('#test').append($( "<ul><li>" + item + " at " + index +"</li>" ));
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="old">
    <li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="new"></ul>
```

It would take the items from `old` and put it in `new`. It seems that it puts all the items into just one `<li>` when it puts it in `new`.

Comment: Where is `#test`? Is having `"<ul><li>"` intended? What exactly do you want to do? Copy the items or moving them?

Answer (score 4):

Simply `clone()` and `appendTo()` the new list first:

```
$('#old > li').clone().appendTo('#new');
```

And then change their `text()`:

```
$('#new > li').text(function (index, text) {
    return text + ' at ' + index;
});
```

A working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vkYUQ/.

---

Or, combine the above into one statement:

```
$('#old > li').clone().text(function (index, text) {
    return text + ' at ' + index;
}).appendTo('#new');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#change").click(function() {
        var old = $("#old");
        var items = $("#old li");
        var newList = $("#new");
        items.each(function(index, value){
            newList.append(value);
        });
        old.empty();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Made a fiddle for you to play with:

http://jsfiddle.net/yEgMK/1/

Now, `clone()` is one way, copying `.html()` is another, and there may be a few others.  Check out the differences in jQuery's API:

http://api.jquery.com/clone/
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data()` for copying and store your HTML in data

```
var $old=$('#old');
$old.data('myhtml',$old.html());
```

To insert a copy into `#test`, you can do

```
var x = $old.data('myhtml');
$(x).appendTo('#test');
```